# Have all require('backbone') statements resolve to the same place using Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have several Backbone plugins along with Backbone itself that I bundle into a `vendor.js` file using Browserify. Backbone itself is being loaded in a module that has been modified to work with Angular. This has resulted in some what of a strange file directory that I'll layout below, which is giving me some issues with Browserifying it all together:

```
src/
  app.js // <- requires angular-backbone and some-backbone-plugin
node_modules/
  backbone/
  underscore/
  angular-backbone/
    main.js // <- requires Backbone and Underscore here 
    node_modules/
      backbone/
      underscore/
  some-backbone-plugin/
    main.js // <- also requires Backbone and Underscore here
    node_modules/
      backbone/
      underscore/
```

When I build `src/app.js`, I get Backbone and Underscore bundled in there twice. Is there a way I can set all `require('backbone')` and `require('underscore')` statement to always resolve to `node_modules/backbone` and `node_modules/underscore` respectively?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating symlink or shortcut-link to the node_modules folder in the other directories.  That way you get one place where all the node_modules are, and everything else is just a shortcut to that main one.

Examples:

```
ln -sF ../../../node_modules/
ln -sF ../node_modules/
```